# get virtual memory size of process in AIX in program

Tags: c++, c, unix, aix, virtual-memory

I write app on AIX 5.3 using C++. I want to get current size of process virtual memory. I use `getprocs64` function, but with this data I can't get result as `svmon` shows.
Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found partially solution that is suitable for me.

I ran small test app and see that `pi_dvm`, the member of `procentry64` structure, will increase if we allocate memory on stack (for example: `char arr[1024];`) for size of allocated object and some overhead. Noiw, we want to calculate used heap size. We should use `mallinfo()` function from `malloc.h` that returns `mallinfo` struct. We are interested in two fields of `mallinfo` structure: `usmblks` and `uordblks` (about this fields you could read [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html)). Some example code:

```
pid_t pid = getpid();
struct procentry64 p_info;
if (getprocs64(&p_info, sizeof(p_info), NULL, 0, &pid, 1) < 0) {
  printf("Error!");
}
proc_size = p_info.pi_dvm*getpagesize() + p_info.pi_tsize;
struct mallinfo m = mallinfo();
proc_size += m.usmblks + m.uordblks;
return proc_size; // proc_size in bytes
```

P.S. I don't know Why we sum `pi_tsize` (if anybody knows, please tell us). I get this idea from [pg_top](https://github.com/markwkm/pg_top/blob/master/machine/m_aix5.c) sources, but there is a bug, they multiply `pi_tsize` by 4, but it's incorrect, because `pi_tsize` is in bytes.
I hope this solution may help someone :)